# Oracle Database connectivity with java

Tags: java, oracle, apache, tomcat, netbeans-7

Connectivity code

```
username="system";
 password="oracle11";
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:system";
 Driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 Class.forName(this.Driver);
 this.con=DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.username,this.password);
 System.out.println("Connect");
```

In the url "system" is globally connect to the oracle it access all the tables so no database security or sepration is there so how to differentiate it.I want to create diffrent database for diffrent projects how to make it in oracle and how to access with java

Comment: You want to [create a new user/schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503)? You're right that you should not be routinely connecting as `system`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't *have* to login with `system`. You can just use a different username / password which has the appropriate access rights setup in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

**Open CMD:**
 1. *sqlplus / as sysdba;*
 2. *create user test identified by 123*;
 3. *grant all privileges to test*;

Here: **test** is the new user whose password is **123**
Now when you need to login with this user
*Type in CMD: Sqlplus test/123*

*Correction:*
In URL:
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:system";

the last parameter should be **SID**

Usually the Service Id is **XE**
 ***url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:XE";***

Comment: so i have to create a user and then i have to pass it in to the DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.username,this.password); am i correct???

Comment: how to connect user through java codeing???

Comment: yes its done DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.username,this.pass‌​word);            in the username and password feild we have to add the particular user's username and password..that's how we can differntiate it....

Comment: Yes correct @hemal. Please mark my answer correct if you find this helpful.